Queueable queue size limits?
I understand that the flex queue allows for a maximum of 100 batchable jobs at a time. Is there a similar limit for Queueable jobs? I’m aware of the global asynchronous limit of 250,000 jobs (or the users × 200 formula, with the option to purchase more), but is there a specific limit on the number of pending Queueable jobs?
The reason I ask as we have a LWC component that will could be making a high number of controller callouts to trigger a large number of Queueables in very short order while I know it may take some time to go through them all it's mostly wanting to know if theres a limit I need to be aware of.

I believe there is not, though there is apparently an org limit on the number of concurrently executing async processes, including Queueables and, as you said, that async execution daily limit.

@PhilW so assuming you don't hit any transaction limit such as 50 in a enqueued in 1 transaction there's no Policy limit? The only limit is how long they will take to be processed due to concurrency limitations.

It is the combo of how fast you can enqueue them (as you said, max of 50 per sync transaction - including in Platform Event trigger based subscriber - and 1 per async transaction), how many can run concurrently (50) and how long they run for, and whether that exceeds the daily limits for asyncs.

BTW, I have not confirmed the purported limit on concurrent async transactions. This is worth testing to check.

@PhilW added bit more to the main but this could be 2000+ Queueable chains in a very short time period

Salesforce does not impose a specific limit on the number of pending Queueable jobs, similar to the 100-job limit for the Flex Queue.
You can enqueue up to 50 Queueable jobs in a single transaction.
When chaining Queueable jobs, you can only chain one job from another, meaning only one child job can be added from a parent job.
As you mentioned, there is a global limit of 250,000 asynchronous Apex method executions per 24-hour period, which includes Queueable, Batch, and future methods.

Adding to Tushar's explanation, the chained Queueable jobs approach is a great way to execute a lot of async work quickly as now the delay from one to the next is not noticeable for multiple jobs until the platform's throttling causes a pause.
Such code was hard to test in a scratch org because the length of the chain was limited to 5 but the ability to set the MaximumQueueableStackDepth avoids that problem. But be aware that MaximumQueueableStackDepth must be set only the first time you enqueue a queueable.
